# Concatenating multiple result rows into a single result without using FOR XML PATH

Tags: .net, sql-server

I've inherited a stored procedure that uses FOR XML PATH in a subselect to concatenate multiple result rows from the subselect into a single result column on the "main" query.  Consider the following, where table "z" is part of the main query's FROM clause:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ('; ' + RTRIM(c.SomeField))
FROM a (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN b (NOLOCK) ON a.aid = b.aid
INNER JOIN c (NOLOCK) ON b.cid = c.cid
WHERE a.zid = z.zid
FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 1000)
```

This returns the following, if there were three result rows from the subselect:

```
value1; value2; value3
```

Most of the time, this works great.  However, several of the values for `c.SomeField`, which is a varchar, have special XML characters in them, most frequently the ampersand.  So, when one of the values has an ampersand, I get this:

```
value1 &amp; more value1; value2; value3
```

Is there another way I can concatenate these row results together?  If not, is there a simple way to decode the string in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MVP [Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path/):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING((
  SELECT ('; ' + RTRIM(c.SomeField))
  FROM a (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN b (NOLOCK) ON a.aid = b.aid
  INNER JOIN c (NOLOCK) ON b.cid = c.cid
  WHERE a.zid = z.zid
  FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('xml'), TYPE
).value('/xml[1]','varchar(max)'), 3, 1000)
```

He points out:

> However, if I actually make my FOR XML
>   call return actual well-formed XML,
>   then I can extract the contents out,
>   and it returns the data to me in its
>   original (correct) form.

Comment: Not sure what .value is, but this works perfectly!  Thank you very much.

Comment: @AJ: The title of this question says *"without using FOR XML PATH"*.

Answer (score 1):

You can run these statements as one batch to get what you want:

```
declare @s as varchar(max); 
select @s = isnull(@s + '; ', '') + SomeField
from (
    SELECT RTRIM(c.SomeField) as SomeField
    FROM a (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN b (NOLOCK) ON a.aid = b.aid 
    INNER JOIN c (NOLOCK) ON b.cid = c.cid 
    WHERE a.zid = z.zid 
) a; 
select @s as SomeFieldList;
```

**Update:** here is a proof of concept without using your schema:

```
declare @s as varchar(max);  
select @s = isnull(@s + '; ', '') + SomeField
from ( 
    SELECT 'aaa' as SomeField
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bbb' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ccc' 
) a;  
select @s as SomeFieldList;
```

Comment: I can't embed this as a subselect though, which is what I need to do.

Comment: Please post the entire query.

Comment: After 40 min of trying to make this procedure "safe to post," I give up.  It's rather massive, and I'm not sure I could put it up here without screwing something up.

Comment: Even running this script alone with a literal value for z.zid doesn't work.